# Jquery events on Jquery Mobile Page After Postback

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

After a form postback, none of the standard Jquery events or functions fire.

I have a search page that posts to itself. Jquery Mobile Ajax loads the search results content, and the page elements are no longer bound. The page hash does not change.

```
    $(document).on('pageshow', '#SearchPage', function (e, data) {
        console.log("This message fires on postback");

       //hide only works the first time
       $('#SearchMenu').hide();

       //does not give accurate results on postback
       var hasSearchResults = $("#SearchWrapper").hasClass("results");

    });
```

What do I have to do to use standard show(), hide(), or hasClass() functions after a postback?

I am using Jquery Mobile 1.4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to switch to classes instead of IDs.

```
 $('.SearchMenu').hide();
```

It doesn't seem to like to rebind using an ID.